# Check if input type file was attached with React.js Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, material-ui

I have a Material UI `<TextField />` component and I would want to trigger an event when a file is attached to it. It is a TextField, but I give to it a `type=file` prop, so it accepts files.
Otherwise, I have no idea how to do it and through the web I only found solutions with JQuery, which I prefer not to use.
Do you know some solution with React, vanilla or something like?

Comment: What do you mean "when an archive is attached to it"? [It's a text field](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/), it contains text.

Comment: Please elaborate and explain your issue. It isnt clear what you mean by archive. Textfields contain text...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  I give to it an `type=file`. Is there a specific component to input a file?

Comment: @Michael I altered the  question right now. Please tell me if it miss something

Comment: it doenst work like that, did you read the API? 
Here is alist of all available params and options: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/
.To use a file upload you can use the input element : https://material-ui.com/api/input/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it like that.
Here is alist of all available params and options for the Text Field: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

To use a file upload you can use the input element : https://material-ui.com/api/input/

you can then check if a file is there like this for example:

```
 <input type="file" onChange={() => console.log("changed")} />
```

Full example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackwell-z7ng2

Comment: Maybe i'm being very inattentive but in the documentation says that the prop type is accepted in TextField component, and the component is currently behaving like a file input. The problem is that I want to trigger an event when a file is attached.

Comment: try it with the input element.

Comment: Look at https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props.
I made a sandbox with the textfield and the type prop: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-waterfall-rfhjv?file=/src/App.js @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I don't know how to do it with the input element. The problem is right here: how to check if the file input was attached? @Michael

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList
You check the filed object on it if it has a length you know it has a file attached.

Comment: The target is trigger an event when the file is uploaded, so the file list is a bit useless here.

Comment: just use the onChange eventhandler ?

Comment: or you mean when upoad is complete? because that happens only when the form is submitted...

Comment: example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackwell-z7ng2